# Mathtype Latex Output - Removing $$ or \[

Tags: math-mode, align, copy-paste

Is there a way to remove the `$$` or `\[ \]` from the latex copy and paste settings on mathtype.

The reason that I need this is I use a series of uncover lines in my beamer presentation within an align environment, e.g.

```
\[
    \begin{aligned}
    \uncover<+->{}
    \uncover<+->{\ddot x}   &   \uncover<.->{=\frac{{dv}}{{dt}}} \\
    \uncover<+->{WOULD PASTE MATHTYPE IN HERE}  &   \uncover<.->{=} \\
        \end{aligned}
\]
```

It is therefore much more convenient to be able to past in the latex maths equations without having to remove the `$$` etc.

Any ideas? Is there an 'equation for application or website' that does this?

Comment: i've removed the `[align]` tag because this applies to *all* math display code.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: This solution works with texstudio and maybe texmaker. For others there maybe alternative solution.
You can copy and paste and then remove $ $ using an script. The following script does that

```
%SCRIPT
var txt = cursor.selectedText()
var str = txt.replace(/[$]/g,"")
editor.replaceSelectedText(str)
cursor.clearSelection()
```

Also, it may be helpful to assign a shortcut to this macro

Comment: Also you can use Lyx instead of Mathtype and  configure it's shortcuts to work like the mathtype or just type with its shortcuts (very similar to mathtype).

Answer (score 0):

Mathtype provides a mechanism for writing new custom output translators. This mechanism is used to implement the translators shipped with Mathtype, and you can use it to write new/custom ones of your own that will plug in directly. Writing a complete translator is quite a bit of work (I've written one myself), but taking an existing one and adapting it a bit shouldn't be too laborious. It's basically just a big list of text-replacement rules. You'll need to get the [MathType SDK](https://www.dessci.com/en/reference/sdk/).